# How to mark a file in a zip as unix executable?

Tags: go, zip

I'd like to write a function like this:

```
func MarkFileAsExecutable(zipPath, filePath string) error
```

It receives a path to a zip and a file path within the zip. The goal is to use the `zip` package to change the ExternalAttributes of the file inside to mark it as a unix executable.

Note that marking the file as executable prior to archiving it using `chmod +x` isn't a solution because I need this to work on Windows. So instead I need to modify the existing zip archive accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `zip` package. It provides a `Reader` and a `Writer`. You open the zip archive with a reader. Then you walk the files in the archive, change your permissions as needed, and copy the files to the writer.

Here is a minimal example, without error checking:

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    r, _ := zip.OpenReader("example.zip")
    defer r.Close()

    f, _ := os.Create("output.zip")
    defer f.Close()

    w := zip.NewWriter(f)
    defer w.Close()

    for _, f := range r.File {
        f.SetMode(0777)
        w.Copy(f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. We can't just edit the archive "in-place" but instead have to copy all the files to a new one and make the necessary changes while doing so. That explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can edit the attributes in place. But you would have to write your own code to process the [zip file format](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).